# Issue with detecting default HTML checked attribute for checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, addclass, checked, removeclass

I'm a bit new to jQuery. I'm having issues with the following code working, specifically the reset button:

```
<script>
$(function() 
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(
        function()
        {
            var cell = $(this).closest('td');
            if($(this).attr('checked'))
            {
                cell.toggleClass('check');
            }
        });
    });
    $('#bay :checkbox').click(function() 
    {
        var cell = $(this).closest('td');
        cell.toggleClass('check');
    }).change();
    $('#reset').click(function()
    {   
    $('#bay input[type=checkbox]').each(function()
    {
        var cell = $(this).closest('td');
        if ($(this).is('checked'))
        {
        //alert("yes");
            cell.addClass('check');

        }
        else
        {
            cell.removeClass('check');
        //alert("no");

        }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<input type="checkbox" checked>Blah
```

For some reason when the reset button is clicked, the script executes only the cell.addClass if statement. Basically, the reset button acts as a restore, and should remove the added class #check from each , if there is no default attribute in the HTML code.

I tried an inefficient method of doing a check of input checkboxes with a checked attribute, and one without, which ran fine in FF and Chrome, but failed in IE. It would only work if you hit the reset button twice.

```
$('#reset').click(function()
{   

    $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(
    function()
    {
        var cell = $(this).closest('td');
        cell.addClass('check');
    });
    $("input[type=checkbox]:not([checked])").each(
    function()
    {
        var cell = $(this).closest('td');
        cell.removeClass('check');
    });
});
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

**Edit:** Per request, the following is a sample of the HTML code w/the working (but INEFFICIENT) jQuery code http://jsfiddle.net/uxjCT/9/.

**Edit2:*** I've simplified the "reset" portion of the code a bit, but it still will not work in IE. Anyone know if this is specifically an IE issue that can't be resolved? Essentially, I'm trying to get the reset function to reset to the defaulted HTML "checked" attribute, for the input checkboxes that have the attribute in the HTML, along with the stylesheet. IE is the only culprit that is a pain right now.

```
$('#reset').click(function(){   

$('#bay input[type=checkbox]').each(function()
{
    var attr = $(this).is("[checked]");
    var cell = $(this).closest('td');

    if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false)
    {
        alert("checked");
        cell.addClass('check');
    }
    else
    {
        alert("unchecked");
        cell.removeClass('check');
    }
    });
});
```

For some reason the `var attr = $(this).is("[checked]");` won't pick up the "checked" attribute in the HTML, but will pick up if the checkbox has been checked, which may be different than the defaulted HTML attribute.

Again, any help would be appreciated!

Demo'd code: http://jsfiddle.net/uxjCT/55/

Comment: Could you please post some HTML markup?

Answer (score 2):

The code to check if a checkbox is checked is

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

not

```
$(this).is('checked')
```

Your code works with this change.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Modifying your code a bit

```
$('#reset').click(function(){   
    $('#bay input:checkbox').each(function()
    {
        var cell = $(this).closest('td');

        if (this.checked)
        {
            //alert("yes");
            cell.addClass('check');
        }
        else
        {
            cell.removeClass('check');
            //alert("no");

        }
    });
});
```

You can try out a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/uxjCT/1/).

Comment: This adds the class "check" to the inputs that were newly checked, but does not reset to checkboxes that had a defaulted HTML "checked" attribute. It's close though.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
 $('#reset').click(function(){   

         cell.removeClass('check');//First remove class from all cell
        $('#bay :checked').each(function()
        {
                cell.addClass('check');//add class only to checked cells

        });
    });
```

Comment: For some reason this code set everything as the class "check" when the "Reset" button was clicked.